# Cannot write to Linux HDD: read-only file system

Tags: permissions

I noticed that I don't have any write access to my entire HDD when my backups started failing.

I understand that I need to change read-only privalges so my user can write to the Disk. However, no matter what I try nothing changes the privalges.

```
garrett@garrett-desktop:/media/garrett$ ls -la
total 12
drwxr-x---+ 3 root    root    4096 Aug  1 20:17  .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root    root    4096 Apr  6 09:13  ..
drwxrwxrwx  1 garrett garrett 4096 Jul  4 18:44 'Garretts HDD'
```

```
garrett$ sudo chmod 777 Garretts\ HDD/
chmod: changing permissions of 'Garretts HDD/': Read-only file system
```

Afterwards I still only have read-only access for my main user `garrett` and the `sudo` user.

Comment: Does "*no matter what I try*" include a plain old unmount/remount? Or a plain old reboot?

Comment: Do you dual boot with Windows?  If so, you must disable "Fast Startup" in Windows because it prevents the system from actually shutting down.  Hard drive failure is another reason that a file system can turn read-only.  Be careful with setting permissions, especially recursively, if there are any system files or software in the destination for your chmod commands

Comment: @Nmath yes, I have a dual boot. I'll look into "Fast Startup" I'm not totally sure what that is. I boot into GRUB at first and my primary option is Ubuntu (so if I do nothing I'm in Ubuntu).

As for HHD failure, I hope that's not the case because I just bought it a month ago and its only purpose is backups for my Linux SSD where the OS is.

Comment: Fast Startup is a Windows setting that does not play nice with dual boot because it is actually a hybrid suspend and it causes Windows to never shut down completely. It also places a "lock" on some hardware and disks. You should be able to search "disable fast startup Windows" to see how to disable it. If I remember correctly, it's an advanced setting under power options

Comment: @Nmath Fast Startup was enabled. You solved my issue! I also needed to reconfigure the `Backups` application in Ubuntu. An additional reason I detest Windows! I just need it for gaming but I have spent hours removing ridiculous configurations to the BIOS.

Comment: @user535733 poor wording. Instead: I tried a few ideas I had from my novice Linux admin skills! Nmath resolved my issue, thanks.